# How can I disable the Android systems navigation gestures in the side of the screen using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing a drawing application using an `AndroidView` which takes the full with of the screen, and the user will be drawing all over the screen. But when the finger touches right or left side of the screen, the app is dragged away and minimized or backstack is popped.

How can I use jetpack compose to disable this behavior only when I am in this `AndroidView` ?